# Error when dragging a view from a docking panel [Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress]

Tags: devexpress, caliburn.micro

It happen to both the example program from the library, and the program I created.

The Caliburn.Micro.DevExpress library was re-compiled with my version of devexpress 13.2. 
I also have reference to the Caliburn.Micro.FrameworkContentElement.2.0.0.4, and Caliburn.Micro 2.0.1.0.

When I drag a view created by a DXDockingScreen inherited viewmodel, it return this error to me.

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in WindowsBase.dll
>
> Additional information: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in
>   use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are using the LayoutGroup.ItemsSource property. In this case the view can be removed from the group only via the ItemsSource collection.

If you want the ability to drag panels out of the group, you should bind your data-collection to the [DockLayoutManager.ItemsSource](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfDockingDockLayoutManager_ItemsSourcetopic) property as shown in the [MVVM Support - Building Dock UI](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument11386) help article. To visualize elements of the ItemsSource collection as layout items, provide templates via the ItemTemplate or ItemTemplateSelector property.